# Cloud Task Creation : Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: grpc, google-cloud-tasks

I'm following thist tutorial :  https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf

To create a Task that would call a cloud function.

I've done quite some tries and still get this error:

[image]

If I change the body encoding to something else, I get another error about serialisation method.

It's likely not a permission issues, as I got some before and got rid of it.

The object which is pass to the createTask() is the following :

```
task: {
  httpRequest: {
    url: "https://europe-west1-project_id.cloudfunctions.net/FunctionName"
    httpMethod: "POST"
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: "cf-targetFunctionSA@project_id.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  body: ""
  headers: {
    Content-Type: "application/json"
  }
}
```

(or with body: base64 encoded json string.)

The code I use is the following :

```
'use strict';
const common            = require('./common');
const {v2beta3}         = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const cloudTasksClient  = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient();

let projectName = common.getProjectName();
let location    = "europe-west3";
let queue       = "compute-stats-on-mysql";
const parent    = cloudTasksClient.queuePath(projectName, location, queue);

async function createTask(url, serviceAccount, data)
{
  const dataBuffer  = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)).toString('base64');
  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url:url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: serviceAccount,
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body:dataBuffer,
    },
  };


  try
  {
    // Send create task request.
    common.logDebug(`Before creating task`, {parent:parent,task:task, data:data});
    const [response] = await cloudTasksClient.createTask({parent, task});
    common.logDebug(`Created task ${response.name}`, {parent:parent,task:task, response:response, data:data});
    return response;
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    // Construct error for Stackdriver Error Reporting
    console.error("error while creating tasks",error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  createTask : createTask,
  cloudTasksClient:cloudTasksClient
};
```

The lack of details in the error makes me hit a wall blind...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

My service account was missing a part...

it was

```
"cf-"+functionName+"@"+projectName+".gserviceaccount.com";
```

instead of

```
"cf-"+functionName+"@"+projectName+".iam.gserviceaccount.com";
```

I left out the ".iam" during my numerous test to make it work.

For sure there's room for improvement in the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. In your case I think there is not property scheduleTime into task param.
To me, the scheduleTime.seconds was with a wrong value.

Comment: I was using `Date.now()` instead of `Date.now() / 1000`

Comment: I misinterpreted the `scheduleTime` thinking it was "from now" rather than "a full timestamp represented in seconds of a date you want it to be at"

So if you want it to be 15 minutes from now, the property would be:
 `seconds: (Date.now() / 1000) + (15 * 60)`

Answer (score 1):

We too faced **"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"** error while triggering the Cloud Workflow via Cloud Tasks at a scheduled date time. Could have been better if they could have provided more information than just this vague INVALID_ARGUMENT as status on task run.

**Error**:

```
attemptResponseLog: {
attemptDuration: "0.026078s"
dispatchCount: "1"
maxAttempts: 0
responseCount: "1"
retryTime: "2023-06-16T12:29:59.466801Z"
scheduleTime: "2023-06-23T12:24:28.851Z"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
targetAddress: "POST https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***/locations/us-central1/workflows/workflow-***/executions"
targetType: "HTTP"
}
```

For us, issue was found with the body payload that was added to httpRequest to Cloud task. Make sure:

1. body of httpRequest object is doubly escaped e.g.

{"argument": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}

2. body has to be base64encoded string if added via REST APIs programatically e.g.

> String payload=String.format("{"argument": "%s"}",
> payload.replace(""", "\""));  String base64EncodedPayload =
> com.google.api.client.util.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(payload.getBytes());//Request
> Body, A base64-encoded string.
>
> httpTargetJSON.put("url",workflowExecutionURL);
> httpTargetJSON.put("httpMethod","POST");
> httpTargetJSON.put("body",base64EncodedPayload);

Equivalent gcloud command would be something as follows (you can quickly run this over cloud console shell/terminal):

gcloud tasks create-http-task     --queue="WorkflowTestQueue"     --url="https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{YourProjectID}/locations/{yourProjectLocation}/workflows/{targetWorkflowID}/executions"     --body-content="{"argument": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}"     --oauth-service-account-email="YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT.gserviceaccount.com"